# How do I tell Finder to read the network folder contents?

Tags: finder, applescript

I use the following AppleScript script to automatically connect a remote drive when my VPN connection is established using Viscosity:

```
do shell script "sleep 5"
tell application "Finder"
    mount volume "smb://some.domain.here/projects"
end tell
```

This works ok. However this does not read the contents of the folder. So when I go to this folder for the first time, it takes extra 30 seconds to retrieve the list of files and folders.

Is there a way to tell Finder to pre-load the content of this network (!) folder in the background, without activation (it is ok to change Finder's folder to /Volumes/projects)? I tried to get a list of files into a variable. I get file names in the variable but the Finder window still tries to pull files again. I tried to "ls /Volumes/projects" but the Finder stills loads files on its own.

The folder is read-only.

Comment: Any particular reason why you’re not just telling Finder to open the newly mounted folder in a window at the end of the script? That won’t get you around the delay (that one is courtesy of Apple’s new SMB stack, [it seems](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3756450?start=0&tstart=0)), but if you don’t jump to that folder right after connecting, you have essentially preloaded it. Also, no need to resort to the shell for `sleep` – AppleScript has a `delay` command.

Comment: Thanks for the "delay" hint.

The connection is slow. I usually select to connect and continue working. The goal is to connect and preload the content of the folder in the background, without flashing Finder on top of other windows.